# Unable to view Python projects in Eclipse IDE

Tags: python, eclipse

> I have installed PyDev Ver 8.3.0 to Eclipse Neon IDE and getting the
> following error. How to fix this error.[Installation and Error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyU2c.jpg)

Comment: Your Eclipse is too old (Eclipse Neon is 13 releases and 5 years behind). Upgrade to the current version.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you download the IDE from a trustworthy source like this:

> https://www.eclipse.org/ide/

After this, navigate to:

- Help > eclipse Marketplace... > Search for PyDev

Good luck, friend!